# Exit Status 11 when trying to install a python package from local source

Tags: python, linux, pip, redhat

I'm trying to install a local source package (called `mypkg`, created with `setuptools`) via pip on a conda environment called `setuptestenv`, but I get this strange error.

```
(setuptestenv) [ccrafter@bumblebee setuptest]$ pip install .
Processing /home/ccrafter/setuptest
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -11:
     command: /home/ccrafter/.conda/envs/setuptestenv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/ccrafter/setuptest/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/ccrafter/setuptest/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev
         cwd: /home/ccrafter/setuptest/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-efdd59ev/mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///home/ccrafter/setuptest. Command errored out with exit status -11: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -11: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

The directory is structured like this:

```
setuptest
  mypkg
    utils
      __init__.py
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    __version__.py
    config.py
  requirements.txt
  setup.py
```

and `setup.py` contains this

```py
"""Metadata for package to allow installation with pip."""

import os

import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

# Use same version from code
# See 3 from
# https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/
version = {}
with open(os.path.join("mypkg", "__version__.py")) as f:
    exec(f.read(), version)  # pylint: disable=W0122

setuptools.setup(
    name="mypkg",
    description="testing",
    version=version["__version__"],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        "numpy"
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "mypkg=mypkg:main",
        ],
    }

)
```

It's odd because it seems to think that `python setup.py egg_info` results in an error, but that output seems to indicate otherwise (at least that's my interpretation).

Anyone able to fix this? I'm on a cluster that runs Red Hat 6.9. The python version in this environment is 3.9.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg\_info Check the logs for full command output. when installing django-haystack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653700/error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-th)

Comment: @TamilSelvan I've installed `setuptools_scm` but I still obtain the same error.